# Git pull только моих веток

Tags: git, контроль-версий, git-pull

У нас очень большой репозиторий, в который коммитят более сотни разработчиков. В результате, когда я делаю `pull` в свой локальный репозиторий, то втягивается очень большое количество ненужных мне боковых веток других разработчиков. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы `pull` втягивал только `master` и мои ветки?

Comment: а вы чем делаете `pull` ? командой из терминала? или каким то IDE?

Comment: Я работаю через Git Extensions.

Comment: Можешь только сделать `git fetch branch-name`. И так все те которые хочешь. Или использовать `IDE`, и там просто в `fetch` оставить только те которые ты хочешь.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26270966/4827341

Comment: Что вы делаете чтобы у вас вот так просто втягивались другие ветки? Какие команды используете?

Comment: @sanmai, команду `pull` программы *git* выполняет автор вопроса. да, по умолчанию из удалённого хранилища копируются все объекты. можно копировать только те, что доступны по указанной метке (меткам): см. мой предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, по умолчанию делается ровно то, что прописано в *fetch* на данный *remote*. И это необязательно все ветки.